# Parsing MIME dates in mail headers (C# but not language related)

Tags: c#, email, mime, datetime-parsing

I'm working on a small local c# app that processes emails. I'm using S22/Imap which downloads and separates headers. When I try to get the Date of the email it returns me the string version, as in MIME headers.

For most of them the DateTime.TryParse runs fine, but for some dates it fails. Here are an example of each of them, I can't find how to process them in the RFC:

- Fri, 15 Jan 2016 20:21:44 **-0600 -0700**
- Mon, 3 Jan 2011 20:32:19 +0000 **(GMT+00:00)**
- Tue, 12 Jun 2012 19:22:28  **0200** (is the + implicit ?)
- Mon, 11 Jan 2010 17:28:39 **3600** (not in the RFC)
- Thu, 07 Oct 2010 17:31:20 **7200**
- Fri, 24 Jul 2009 21:13:28 +0100 **(Paris, Madrid)** (do I have to ignore what follows the +0100 ? can I without loss of information ?)
- Thu, 28 May 2015 10:58:24 +0200 **(Paris, Madrid (heure d'été))** (same question)

Could anyone tell me the meaning of the first five, or point me out a documentation that would explain the other format ?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: They seems as UTC Offset and time zone abbreviations.

Comment: wow, thats some differences there, I noticed the 7200 and 3600 actually represent seconds. 7200=2 hours, 3600=1 hour but Ive never seen that before..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to write my own class to parse these (if your interested, I have a competing library to S22.Imap called [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) which uses my [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) library for parsing messages, dates, etc).

I've taken the liberty of splitting my date parser out of MimeKit in order to paste it here as a stand-alone

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DateParserUtils {
    [Flags]
    enum DateTokenFlags : byte
    {
        None           = 0,
        NonNumeric     = (1 << 0),
        NonWeekday     = (1 << 1),
        NonMonth       = (1 << 2),
        NonTime        = (1 << 3),
        NonAlphaZone   = (1 << 4),
        NonNumericZone = (1 << 5),
        HasColon       = (1 << 6),
        HasSign        = (1 << 7),
    }

    class DateToken
    {
        public DateTokenFlags Flags { get; private set; }
        public int StartIndex { get; private set; }
        public int Length { get; private set; }

        public bool IsNumeric {
            get { return (Flags & DateTokenFlags.NonNumeric) == 0; }
        }

        public bool IsWeekday {
            get { return (Flags & DateTokenFlags.NonWeekday) == 0; }
        }

        public bool IsMonth {
            get { return (Flags & DateTokenFlags.NonMonth) == 0; }
        }

        public bool IsTimeOfDay {
            get { return (Flags & DateTokenFlags.NonTime) == 0 && (Flags & DateTokenFlags.HasColon) != 0; }
        }

        public bool IsNumericZone {
            get { return (Flags & DateTokenFlags.NonNumericZone) == 0 && (Flags & DateTokenFlags.HasSign) != 0; }
        }

        public bool IsAlphaZone {
            get { return (Flags & DateTokenFlags.NonAlphaZone) == 0; }
        }

        public bool IsTimeZone {
            get { return IsNumericZone || IsAlphaZone; }
        }

        public DateToken (DateTokenFlags flags, int startIndex, int length)
        {
            StartIndex = startIndex;
            Length = length;
            Flags = flags;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Utility methods to parse and format rfc822 date strings.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Utility methods to parse and format rfc822 date strings.
    /// </remarks>
    public static class DateUtils
    {
        internal static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch = new DateTime (1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        const string MonthCharacters = "JanuaryFebruaryMarchAprilMayJuneJulyAugustSeptemberOctoberNovemberDecember";
        const string WeekdayCharacters = "SundayMondayTuesdayWednesdayThursdayFridaySaturday";
        const string AlphaZoneCharacters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        const string NumericZoneCharacters = "+-0123456789";
        const string NumericCharacters = "0123456789";
        const string TimeCharacters = "0123456789:";

        static readonly string[] Months = {
            "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
            "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"
        };

        static readonly string[] WeekDays = {
            "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"
        };

        static readonly Dictionary<string, int> timezones;
        static readonly DateTokenFlags[] datetok;

        static DateUtils ()
        {
            timezones = new Dictionary<string, int> {
                { "UT",       0 }, { "UTC",      0 }, { "GMT",      0 },
                { "EDT",   -400 }, { "EST",   -500 },
                { "CDT",   -500 }, { "CST",   -600 },
                { "MDT",   -600 }, { "MST",   -700 },
                { "PDT",   -700 }, { "PST",   -800 },
                // Note: rfc822 got the signs backwards for the military
                // timezones so some sending clients may mistakenly use the
                // wrong values.
                { "A",      100 }, { "B",      200 }, { "C",      300 },
                { "D",      400 }, { "E",      500 }, { "F",      600 },
                { "G",      700 }, { "H",      800 }, { "I",      900 },
                { "K",     1000 }, { "L",     1100 }, { "M",     1200 },
                { "N",     -100 }, { "O",     -200 }, { "P",     -300 },
                { "Q",     -400 }, { "R",     -500 }, { "S",     -600 },
                { "T",     -700 }, { "U",     -800 }, { "V",     -900 },
                { "W",    -1000 }, { "X",    -1100 }, { "Y",    -1200 },
                { "Z",        0 },
            };

            datetok = new DateTokenFlags[256];
            var any = new char[2];

            for (int c = 0; c < 256; c++) {
                if (c >= 0x41 && c <= 0x5a) {
                    any[1] = (char) (c + 0x20);
                    any[0] = (char) c;
                } else if (c >= 0x61 && c <= 0x7a) {
                    any[0] = (char) (c - 0x20);
                    any[1] = (char) c;
                }

                if (NumericZoneCharacters.IndexOf ((char) c) == -1)
                    datetok[c] |= DateTokenFlags.NonNumericZone;
                if (AlphaZoneCharacters.IndexOf ((char) c) == -1)
                    datetok[c] |= DateTokenFlags.NonAlphaZone;
                if (WeekdayCharacters.IndexOfAny (any) == -1)
                    datetok[c] |= DateTokenFlags.NonWeekday;
                if (NumericCharacters.IndexOf ((char) c) == -1)
                    datetok[c] |= DateTokenFlags.NonNumeric;
                if (MonthCharacters.IndexOfAny (any) == -1)
                    datetok[c] |= DateTokenFlags.NonMonth;
                if (TimeCharacters.IndexOf ((char) c) == -1)
                    datetok[c] |= DateTokenFlags.NonTime;
            }

            datetok[':'] |= DateTokenFlags.HasColon;
            datetok['+'] |= DateTokenFlags.HasSign;
            datetok['-'] |= DateTokenFlags.HasSign;
        }

        static bool TryGetWeekday (DateToken token, byte[] text, out DayOfWeek weekday)
        {
            weekday = DayOfWeek.Sunday;

            if (!token.IsWeekday || token.Length < 3)
                return false;

            var name = Encoding.ASCII.GetString (text, token.StartIndex, token.Length);

            if (name.Length > 3)
                name = name.Substring (0, 3);

            for (int day = 0; day < WeekDays.Length; day++) {
                if (WeekDays[day].Equals (name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                    weekday = (DayOfWeek) day;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        static bool TryParseInt32 (byte[] text, ref int index, int endIndex, out int value)
        {
            int startIndex = index;

            value = 0;

            while (index < endIndex && text[index] >= (byte) '0' && text[index] <= (byte) '9') {
                int digit = text[index] - (byte) '0';

                if (value > int.MaxValue / 10) {
                    // integer overflow
                    return false;
                }

                if (value == int.MaxValue / 10 && digit > int.MaxValue % 10) {
                    // integer overflow
                    return false;
                }

                value = (value * 10) + digit;
                index++;
            }

            return index > startIndex;
        }

        static bool TryGetDayOfMonth (DateToken token, byte[] text, out int day)
        {
            int endIndex = token.StartIndex + token.Length;
            int index = token.StartIndex;

            day = 0;

            if (!token.IsNumeric)
                return false;

            if (!TryParseInt32 (text, ref index, endIndex, out day))
                return false;

            if (day <= 0 || day > 31)
                return false;

            return true;
        }

        static bool TryGetMonth (DateToken token, byte[] text, out int month)
        {
            month = 0;

            if (!token.IsMonth || token.Length < 3)
                return false;

            var name = Encoding.ASCII.GetString (text, token.StartIndex, token.Length);

            if (name.Length > 3)
                name = name.Substring (0, 3);

            for (int i = 0; i < Months.Length; i++) {
                if (Months[i].Equals (name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                    month = i + 1;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        static bool TryGetYear (DateToken token, byte[] text, out int year)
        {
            int endIndex = token.StartIndex + token.Length;
            int index = token.StartIndex;

            year = 0;

            if (!token.IsNumeric)
                return false;

            if (!TryParseInt32 (text, ref index, endIndex, out year))
                return false;

            if (year < 100)
                year += (year < 70) ? 2000 : 1900;

            return year >= 1969;
        }

        static bool TryGetTimeOfDay (DateToken token, byte[] text, out int hour, out int minute, out int second)
        {
            int endIndex = token.StartIndex + token.Length;
            int index = token.StartIndex;

            hour = minute = second = 0;

            if (!token.IsTimeOfDay)
                return false;

            if (!TryParseInt32 (text, ref index, endIndex, out hour) || hour > 23)
                return false;

            if (index >= endIndex || text[index++] != (byte) ':')
                return false;

            if (!TryParseInt32 (text, ref index, endIndex, out minute) || minute > 59)
                return false;

            // Allow just hh:mm (i.e. w/o the :ss?)
            if (index >= endIndex || text[index++] != (byte) ':')
                return true;

            if (!TryParseInt32 (text, ref index, endIndex, out second) || second > 59)
                return false;

            return index == endIndex;
        }

        static bool TryGetTimeZone (DateToken token, byte[] text, out int tzone)
        {
            tzone = 0;

            if (token.IsNumericZone) {
                int endIndex = token.StartIndex + token.Length;
                int index = token.StartIndex;
                int sign;

                if (text[index] == (byte) '-')
                    sign = -1;
                else if (text[index] == (byte) '+')
                    sign = 1;
                else
                    return false;

                index++;

                if (!TryParseInt32 (text, ref index, endIndex, out tzone) || index != endIndex)
                    return false;

                tzone *= sign;
            } else if (token.IsAlphaZone) {
                if (token.Length > 3)
                    return false;

                var name = Encoding.ASCII.GetString (text, token.StartIndex, token.Length);

                if (!timezones.TryGetValue (name, out tzone))
                    return false;
            } else if (token.IsNumeric) {
                int endIndex = token.StartIndex + token.Length;
                int index = token.StartIndex;

                if (!ParseUtils.TryParseInt32 (text, ref index, endIndex, out tzone) || index != endIndex)
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        static bool IsWhiteSpace (byte c)
        {
            return c == ' ' || c == '\t';
        }

        static bool IsTokenDelimeter (byte c)
        {
            return c == (byte) '-' || c == (byte) '/' || c == (byte) ',' || IsWhiteSpace (c);
        }

        static bool SkipWhiteSpace (byte[] text, ref int index, int endIndex)
        {
            int startIndex = index;

            while (index < endIndex && IsWhiteSpace (text[index]))
                index++;

            return index > startIndex;
        }

        static bool SkipComment (byte[] text, ref int index, int endIndex)
        {
            bool escaped = false;
            int depth = 1;

            index++;

            while (index < endIndex && depth > 0) {
                if (text[index] == (byte) '\\') {
                    escaped = !escaped;
                } else if (!escaped) {
                    if (text[index] == (byte) '(')
                        depth++;
                    else if (text[index] == (byte) ')')
                        depth--;
                    escaped = false;
                } else {
                    escaped = false;
                }

                index++;
            }

            return depth == 0;
        }

        static bool SkipCommentsAndWhiteSpace (byte[] text, ref int index, int endIndex)
        {
            SkipWhiteSpace (text, ref index, endIndex);

            while (index < endIndex && text[index] == (byte) '(') {
                int startIndex = index;

                if (!SkipComment (text, ref index, endIndex))
                    return false;

                SkipWhiteSpace (text, ref index, endIndex);
            }

            return true;
        }

        static IEnumerable<DateToken> TokenizeDate (byte[] text, int startIndex, int length)
        {
            int endIndex = startIndex + length;
            int index = startIndex;
            DateTokenFlags mask;
            int start;

            while (index < endIndex) {
                if (!SkipCommentsAndWhiteSpace (text, ref index, endIndex))
                    break;

                if (index >= endIndex)
                    break;

                // get the initial mask for this token
                if ((mask = datetok[text[index]]) != DateTokenFlags.None) {
                    start = index++;

                    // find the end of this token
                    while (index < endIndex && !IsTokenDelimeter (text[index]))
                        mask |= datetok[text[index++]];

                    yield return new DateToken (mask, start, index - start);
                }

                // skip over the token delimeter
                index++;
            }

            yield break;
        }

        static bool TryParseStandardDateFormat (IList<DateToken> tokens, byte[] text, out DateTimeOffset date)
        {
            int day, month, year, tzone;
            int hour, minute, second;
            DayOfWeek weekday;
            //bool haveWeekday;
            int n = 0;

            date = new DateTimeOffset ();

            // we need at least 5 tokens, 6 if we have a weekday
            if (tokens.Count < 5)
                return false;

            // Note: the weekday is not required
            if (TryGetWeekday (tokens[n], text, out weekday)) {
                if (tokens.Count < 6)
                    return false;

                //haveWeekday = true;
                n++;
            }

            if (!TryGetDayOfMonth (tokens[n++], text, out day))
                return false;

            if (!TryGetMonth (tokens[n++], text, out month))
                return false;

            if (!TryGetYear (tokens[n++], text, out year))
                return false;

            if (!TryGetTimeOfDay (tokens[n++], text, out hour, out minute, out second))
                return false;

            if (!TryGetTimeZone (tokens[n], text, out tzone))
                tzone = 0;

            while (tzone < -1400)
                tzone += 2400;

            while (tzone > 1400)
                tzone -= 2400;

            int minutes = tzone % 100;
            int hours = tzone / 100;

            var offset = new TimeSpan (hours, minutes, 0);

            try {
                date = new DateTimeOffset (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, offset);
            } catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        static bool TryParseUnknownDateFormat (IList<DateToken> tokens, byte[] text, out DateTimeOffset date)
        {
            int? day = null, month = null, year = null, tzone = null;
            int hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0;
            bool numericMonth = false;
            bool haveWeekday = false;
            bool haveTime = false;
            DayOfWeek weekday;
            TimeSpan offset;

            for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Count; i++) {
                int value;

                if (!haveWeekday && tokens[i].IsWeekday) {
                    if (TryGetWeekday (tokens[i], text, out weekday)) {
                        haveWeekday = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if ((month == null || numericMonth) && tokens[i].IsMonth) {
                    if (TryGetMonth (tokens[i], text, out value)) {
                        if (numericMonth) {
                            numericMonth = false;
                            day = month;
                        }

                        month = value;
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if (!haveTime && tokens[i].IsTimeOfDay) {
                    if (TryGetTimeOfDay (tokens[i], text, out hour, out minute, out second)) {
                        haveTime = true;
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if (tzone == null && tokens[i].IsTimeZone) {
                    if (TryGetTimeZone (tokens[i], text, out value)) {
                        tzone = value;
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if (tokens[i].IsNumeric) {
                    if (tokens[i].Length == 4) {
                        if (year == null) {
                            if (TryGetYear (tokens[i], text, out value))
                                year = value;
                        } else if (tzone == null) {
                            if (TryGetTimeZone (tokens[i], text, out value))
                                tzone = value;
                        }

                        continue;
                    }

                    if (tokens[i].Length > 2)
                        continue;

                    // Note: we likely have either YYYY[-/]MM[-/]DD or MM[-/]DD[-/]YY
                    int endIndex = tokens[i].StartIndex + tokens[i].Length;
                    int index = tokens[i].StartIndex;

                    TryParseInt32 (text, ref index, endIndex, out value);

                    if (month == null && value > 0 && value <= 12) {
                        numericMonth = true;
                        month = value;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (day == null && value > 0 && value <= 31) {
                        day = value;
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (year == null && value >= 69) {
                        year = 1900 + value;
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                // WTF is this??
            }

            if (year == null || month == null || day == null) {
                date = new DateTimeOffset ();
                return false;
            }

            if (!haveTime)
                hour = minute = second = 0;

            if (tzone != null) {
                int minutes = tzone.Value % 100;
                int hours = tzone.Value / 100;

                offset = new TimeSpan (hours, minutes, 0);
            } else {
                offset = new TimeSpan (0);
            }

            try {
                date = new DateTimeOffset (year.Value, month.Value, day.Value, hour, minute, second, offset);
            } catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) {
                date = new DateTimeOffset ();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tries to parse the given input buffer into a new <see cref="System.DateTimeOffset"/> instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Parses an rfc822 date and time from the supplied buffer starting at the given index
        /// and spanning across the specified number of bytes.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns><c>true</c>, if the date was successfully parsed, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
        /// <param name="buffer">The input buffer.</param>
        /// <param name="startIndex">The starting index of the input buffer.</param>
        /// <param name="length">The number of bytes in the input buffer to parse.</param>
        /// <param name="date">The parsed date.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">
        /// <paramref name="buffer"/> is <c>null</c>.
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
        /// <paramref name="startIndex"/> and <paramref name="length"/> do not specify
        /// a valid range in the byte array.
        /// </exception>
        public static bool TryParse (byte[] buffer, int startIndex, int length, out DateTimeOffset date)
        {
            if (buffer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException ("buffer");

            if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex > buffer.Length)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("startIndex");

            if (length < 0 || length > (buffer.Length - startIndex))
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("length");

            var tokens = new List<DateToken> (TokenizeDate (buffer, startIndex, length));

            if (TryParseStandardDateFormat (tokens, buffer, out date))
                return true;

            if (TryParseUnknownDateFormat (tokens, buffer, out date))
                return true;

            date = new DateTimeOffset ();

            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tries to parse the given input buffer into a new <see cref="System.DateTimeOffset"/> instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Parses an rfc822 date and time from the supplied buffer starting at the specified index.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns><c>true</c>, if the date was successfully parsed, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
        /// <param name="buffer">The input buffer.</param>
        /// <param name="startIndex">The starting index of the input buffer.</param>
        /// <param name="date">The parsed date.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">
        /// <paramref name="buffer"/> is <c>null</c>.
        /// </exception>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
        /// <paramref name="startIndex"/> is not within the range of the byte array.
        /// </exception>
        public static bool TryParse (byte[] buffer, int startIndex, out DateTimeOffset date)
        {
            if (buffer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException ("buffer");

            if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex > buffer.Length)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("startIndex");

            int length = buffer.Length - startIndex;
            var tokens = new List<DateToken> (TokenizeDate (buffer, startIndex, length));

            if (TryParseStandardDateFormat (tokens, buffer, out date))
                return true;

            if (TryParseUnknownDateFormat (tokens, buffer, out date))
                return true;

            date = new DateTimeOffset ();

            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tries to parse the given input buffer into a new <see cref="System.DateTimeOffset"/> instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Parses an rfc822 date and time from the specified buffer.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns><c>true</c>, if the date was successfully parsed, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
        /// <param name="buffer">The input buffer.</param>
        /// <param name="date">The parsed date.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">
        /// <paramref name="buffer"/> is <c>null</c>.
        /// </exception>
        public static bool TryParse (byte[] buffer, out DateTimeOffset date)
        {
            if (buffer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException ("buffer");

            var tokens = new List<DateToken> (TokenizeDate (buffer, 0, buffer.Length));

            if (TryParseStandardDateFormat (tokens, buffer, out date))
                return true;

            if (TryParseUnknownDateFormat (tokens, buffer, out date))
                return true;

            date = new DateTimeOffset ();

            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Tries to parse the given input buffer into a new <see cref="System.DateTimeOffset"/> instance.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Parses an rfc822 date and time from the specified text.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <returns><c>true</c>, if the date was successfully parsed, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
        /// <param name="text">The input text.</param>
        /// <param name="date">The parsed date.</param>
        /// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">
        /// <paramref name="text"/> is <c>null</c>.
        /// </exception>
        public static bool TryParse (string text, out DateTimeOffset date)
        {
            if (text == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException ("text");

            var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (text);
            var tokens = new List<DateToken> (TokenizeDate (buffer, 0, buffer.Length));

            if (TryParseStandardDateFormat (tokens, buffer, out date))
                return true;

            if (TryParseUnknownDateFormat (tokens, buffer, out date))
                return true;

            date = new DateTimeOffset ();

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code! I tried to use it (converting the result with ToUniversalTime() as it is an offset) like I did after the DateTime.Tryparse, but it always gives me a good datetime MINUS 1 hour, whatever it's +0100, GMT, +0800...
Am I using it the bad way ?
----
I think I'll have a look on your link, because the closeness to the RFC (even the military timezones ! which I wasn't going to implement) is interesting, but I would like to be sure the sample code you gave me is working before.
I'd like to know what you think about the example dates i've given.
(PS: sorry for my english)

Comment: Weird, I don't seem to have the problem you describe with ToUniversalTime(). Does the output of the TryParse() method have the correct date/time and timezone offset? It does for me (except in the cases where the date strings in your example don't have a +/- sign in front of the offsets).

Comment: As far as the example dates given... the dates with a timezone of 3600 and 7200 are completely broken. Might be possible to handle them, but the developers clearly had no idea how to express a timezone. Date strings with info in ()'s is perfectly acceptable, but in general the parser should ignore those (they are just comments).

Comment: FWIW, I've just patched MimeKit's date parser to handle date strings containing timezones w/o a leading '+': https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/commit/d46b390a0c908688d225e469a917d5c98d02b9f3

Comment: Looks like I was wrong when getting the datetime out of the datetime offset, when I call 
`myDate = retval.ToUniversalTime().DateTime;`
instead of
`myDate = retval.DateTime.ToUniversalTime();` (as I was doing) it works better.

So if I list all answers:
- everything between ( ) can be ignored
- timezones can be signed explicitly or implicitly
- I guess that when more than one timezone is mentioned, only the first one is taken into account (?)
- 3600 and 7200 should be ignored

If you confirm the "(?)" I think I can validate your answer.

Comment: The specification states that timezones must be signed explicitly, but I've updated the parser to handle unsigned timezones in MimeKit (I haven't updated the answer yet). When more than 1 timezone is mentioned, my parser only takes the first one. In the case of 3600 and 7200, I think my parser will take those and adjust the as if they were 36 hours and 72 hours, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the time you took to help me @jstedfast :) I think I'll explore your library more in-depth, Google did not tell me about it before you did.

Comment: No problem. Sadly, email is something that is very hard to do because so much software doesn't follow the spec :(

Answer (score 0):

On my app I am saving some emails into the database so using SQL server I was able to do this in a very simple way using PARSE().

SELECT PARSE('Wed, 28 Sep 2022 17:04:44 -0500' AS datetime)